# How do i make RichTextEditor not to include the Typography stuff in the markup?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, rich-text-editor

when i want to save the text to the database it adds all these typography stuff to it .
Is there a way to get rid of these typography stuff from my markup?

Here is an example

```
<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" CharacterSpacing="0" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="0" LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight"><Run>Blah text here</Run></Paragraph></Section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the xml you want to get rid of and do

```
 //Match [Prefix][any number of Not =][=]["][any number of Not "]["][ ] <-must have space!!!
            string replace = "Typography[^\\=]*=\"[^\"]*\" ";
            XMLString = Regex.Replace(XMLString, replace, string.Empty);
```